# Is there something like the Tag property (.NET) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, controls

For example in VB.NET:

```
btnSend.Tag = "Hello"
```

Can I do something similar in JavaScript?

```
document.getElementById("btnSend").tag = "Hello"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just store data in a var.

Answer (score 0):

The `Tag` property in visual basic is meant to store the object that contains data for the control that owns the `Tag` property.

In javascript you normaly store such information inside the data-attribute.

You can write:

```
document.getElementbyId('btnSend').dataset.tag = 'Hello';
```

This stores the value `Hello` inside the elements `data-tag` property and you can read it out later when you need it.